# Close Modal After Smooth Scrolling Reaches Anchor

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Bootstrap and the regular nav currently uses a smooth scrolling script that goes to the sections of the page.

For mobile, I have a fullscreen nav modal that opens once you click the hamburger icon. It will use smooth scrolling as well but I can't seem to get the modal to close once you click on a link in the menu and it brings you to the section.

Script

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').hide();
```

or maybe

```
$('#myModal').remove();
```

Comment: I figured out the mistake. I just added it to trigger right after the menu scrolls. So right before the return statement.